# How to get fontWeight in React native androidI

Tags: react-native

```
fontSize: 22,
        fontWeight: '500,
        fontFamily: "Montserrat-Regular"
```

Font weight is not working in Android using react-native. As I am using fontWeight from 100-500 it is showing regular font but as I change it to 600-900 giving me bold font. How can I get this for this for

100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the font weight seems not to be handled on Android.
I would remove the fontWeight field and set the weight with the fontFamily.

For example:

```
    fontSize: 22,
    fontFamily: "Montserrat-Light"
```

Comment: HI @JSharles as font weight is used in the whole app. it will take so much time to change it's family. Is there any other alternative that it effective.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this is how I got to solve the issue.  I'll be happy to hear about any other alternative.

Comment: Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the font weight field. Android/React native only supports certain font weights and my `fontWeight: '500` was over-riding the `fontFamily: "Montserrat-Light"` which already has the font weight build into it. Control the font weights using `Light`, `bold`...etc